# add a class to a table row onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a class to a table row onclick:

```
<tr class="gradeA " onclick="window.location.href='games/BG-1001.php'; obj.className='diagram-popup';" >
```

...

```
<!--Another Pop-up for diagram-->
<script src="js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script> 
<script>
    $('.diagram-popup').popupWindow({centerBrowser:1, height:560, width:1024});
</script>
```

How can I do this? The `obj.className='diagram-popup';` syntax appears to be wrong.

Comment: You would use `this.className` in that context. And you're not actually adding it, but replacing what was there before.

Comment: Also, don't forget to review past questions and select appropriate answers when possible by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why use so many complications ?

Using jQuery provides a keyword `this`

Which u can use like this :

```
<tr class="add">Some thing</tr>
```

And jquery like :

```
$('.add').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('addedclass');
})
```

Comment: Still broke dataTables.<script src="js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script> 
<script>$('.diagram-popup').popupWindow({centerBrowser:1, height:560, width:1024}); </script>
<script>$('.add').click(function() {$(this).addClass('diagram-popup');})</script> and the <tr> looked like this: <tr class="gradeA add " onclick="window.location.href='games/BG-1001.php';" ><td>07/17/1998</td><td>EU-ch U12</td><td>Mureck</td><td>0000</td><td>Khramiankov, Yuri</td><td>B99
</td></tr> the source is posted at: http://chesstao.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, use `this` in that context:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="this.className='test';alert(this.className);">
        <td>Click me (I will replace the className)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr onclick="this.className+=' test';alert(this.className);">
        <td>Click me to add (I will add to the className, click more than once)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>Click me for jQuery handler (I will only add classes once when clicked more than once)</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('.test').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('test'); // Note, will not add the same class more than once
    alert(this.className);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/NBU8L/

If you're using jQuery, I would steer clear of inline handlers and use jQuery's handlers for this:

```
$('.gradeA').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('diagram-popup')
           .popupWindow({
               centerBrowser:1,
               height:560,
               width:1024
           });
});
```

Comment: I would do that but it breaks the dataTables.js jquery plugin. I need to set the URL in the <TR> tag. Is this correct: <!--Another Pop-up for diagram--> 
<script src="js/jquery.popupWindow-min.js" ></script> 
<!--<script>$('.diagram-popup').popupWindow({centerBrowser:1, height:560, width:1024}); </script>--> 
<script> 
$('.gradeA').click(function(){
    $(this).popupWindow({centerBrowser:1, height:560, width:1024});
});</script>

Comment: You would do what? Refrain from using jQuery handlers? The first part of the question answers your question specifically.

Comment: Are you putting a `SCRIPT` tag in the `TR` markup? And yes, that looks right to me, although I'm not real sure what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I am. It's the only way to put an URL in a TR tag.

Comment: So when you click on the row, you want the browser to go to another `href`? How does the `popupWindow` fit in?

Comment: The popupWindow loads another specified URL that is sized smaller (not full size) and is the game moves of the table row item.

Comment: The answer to the main question, how to manipulate the class name from an `onclick` handler, is to use `this.className`. The rest of your problem I suggest you open another question, because I don't follow and it doesn't have to do with this question, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by taking advantage of the [Element Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) and [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) (to manage event handling). You'd want to take note of how `handleClick` works in the code below (most of the other code is simply to show how to setup table using the Web API, instead of writing out the HTML) - comments are pretty explanatory, but lmk if you have further questions:

```js
// Reference to our table DOM element
const tableEl = document.querySelector('#tableEl');

// Style class we want to add to clicked rows
const cls = "foo";

// Function to generate a single tr element to add to our table
const generateTrEl = i => {
  const trEl = document.createElement('tr'); // Create a tr
  const tdEl = document.createElement('td'); // Create a td to go inside tr
  trEl.setAttribute('class', 'gradeA'); // Add the specified attribute
  tdEl.setAttribute('colspan', '1'); // Set the colspan to stretch whole table
  tdEl.insertAdjacentText('afterbegin', i); // Insert the text in the td
  trEl.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', tdEl); // Insert the td in the tr

  return trEl;
};

// Event handling function that takes advantage of event delegation (so we don't have to manage multiple listners in our code)
const handleClick = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
    e.target.classList.add(cls);
  }
};

// Setup the table for testing functionality 
const init = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    tableEl.appendChild(generateTrEl(i));
  }

  tableEl.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
};

init();
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableEl" border="1" width="300px"></table>
```